# Поиск элементов с одинаковой длиной в кортеже

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, кортежи

Получаю данные бд в кортеж, после этого мне нужно отделить номер телефона и изменить его. Была идея превратить кортеж в строку, но как дальше вырезать номер из строки не понял. Пытался реализовать поиск по длине, но со вложенным кортежем это кажется невозможным. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону думать.

```
def execute_read_query(connection, query):
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = None
try:
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
except Error as e:
    print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")

select_persdata = "SELECT * from personal"
numbers = execute_read_query(connection, select_persdata)

for user in numbers:
    print(user)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас буду пробовать разделить кортеж на малые вложенные кортежи, потом извлекать данные уже из малых кортежей.

Comment: Изменить номер нужно где, в БД в итоге или куда или зачем? А так то ну у вас кортеж из 4-х элементов, номер у вас в 3-м элементе, это индекс 2: `user[2]` - тут номер. В чём проблема, собственно? Вложенных кортежей у вас нет, у вас есть список кортежей `numbers`.

Comment: Сейчас объясню, нужно изменить номер телефона определенного человека в алгоритме, потом передать его обратно в базу данных, то есть изменить. Когда я получаю данные таблицы person, формируется вложенный кортеж numbers из 4 элементов, в каждом из которых 4 элемента. Вопрос в том, как определить что номер телефона стоит на 3 месте в элементе кортежа.

Comment: Проще всего указать в `SELECT` не `*`, а конкретные поля в конкретном порядке, тогда вы точно будете знать на каком месте какое поле.

Comment: Фокус в том что я по идее не должен знать на каких местах будут стоять номер телефона или фио например. Наверное я неправильно задал вопрос и указал теги, вопрос склоняется в общем к безопасности. В любом случае спасибо, я вроде как додумался, если преобразовать кортеж в список, формируется двумерный список, отсюда уже проще работать.

Comment: Там как-то можно и при вашем селекте со звёздочкой посмотреть заголовки колонок, но я не помню как. Всё же надёжнее указывать колонки конкретно.

Comment: Подскажите еще одну вещь пожалуйста, вот я преобразовал кортеж в список, взял из бд пока что только 1 строку, на выводе такое: [(1, 'Петрова Анастасия Ивановна', '+78005553535', '123456237562\n')]. Вроде бы 1 элемент списка, но список многомерный, так вот, могу ли я через цикл For записывать элементы в переменную?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137414/discussion-between---and-crazyelf).